# How to set Datazoom for all axis on SingleAxis in Baidu's echarts?

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, echarts, baidu

Is it possible to set an 'inside' Datazoom for each axis on the SingleAxis chart?

I'm using the following example but adding dataZoom object only works for the first axis.
https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=scatter-single-axis

I used this dataZoom : 
const options = {
          ...
          dataZoom: [{
                  type: 'inside',
          },
          {
                  type: 'inside',
          }],
          ...
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Angular folks using ngx-echart, the accepted did not work for me .'

Using `xAxisIndex` with array works in my case.

```
dataZoom: [
    {
      type: 'slider',
      bottom: 0,
      xAxisIndex: [0,1,2,3,4]
    }];
```

Answer (score 2):

[Yes](https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/blob/master/src/component/dataZoom/DataZoomModel.js#L36), just pass to slider attribute `singleAxisIndex` array of each axis index.

```js
dataZoom: [{
  type: 'slider',
  //...
  singleAxisIndex: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
  //...
}
```